# Form layout I created in QGIS won't transfer to QField

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qfield, format, qfieldsync

I have been trying to create a form layout in QGIS which includes different tabs, and am trying to transfer this layout to QField. When I open QField, my fields are showing up but that is it, none of the tabs or fields are organized even though I saved my form layout in QGIS prior to transferring it to QField. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I've created something similar a while ago and didn't have this problem, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to select the option `Properties...` (right-click on the desired layer), then on the left panel, choose `Attributes Form`.

At the top of the window, locate the upper dropdown and select the option `Drag and Drop Designer`:

[image: Drag and Drop Designer]

Then, click on the plus icon next to the `Form Layout Panel`, and create a container with the desired name as **a tab**:

[image: Crete a tab]

Drag the container at the beginning of the list and create another container, but now as **a group in container** related to the container created lately:

[image: Create a group in container]

You can create the number of tabs and groups as you require it.

Now, drag the fields of your layer inside of the Tab or the Group desire. Like this:

[image: Setup]

Save the setup clicking `OK` on the `Layer Properties` window. The form looks like this in QGIS:

[image: QGIS Form]

And like this in QField:

[image: QField form]

Save the project on QGIS and copy it to your device with QField.

Comment: Example using QGIS 3.22.3-Białowieża and QField 2.3.2 Diversified Dugong. Geopackage polygon and project saved as *.qgz*.